# If $G$ is a subgroup of the circle, then why is $\{(\text{id}\colon G\to\mathbb{T})^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ dense in the dual $\widehat{G}$?

Tags: general-topology, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, duality-theorems, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be any subgroup of the circle $\mathbb{T}$ and endow $G$ with the discrete topology. Let $$\text{id}\colon G\to\mathbb{T}$$ be the inclusion map. Why is $$\{\text{id}^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ dense in the (compact) Pontryagin dual group $\widehat{G}$?

I tried to work with nets, but I struggled with the topology on $\widehat{G}$ and it got quite messy. Is there a more elegant argument?

Comment: What do you mean by discrete? Topologically discrete? If so $G$ would be finite and you should have $\widehat{G}=\{\mathrm{id}^n\mid n=0,\dots,|G|-1\}$, no?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Topologically discrete, yes. But not with the subspace topology. I'll make this more clear in the main post.

Comment: Ok.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially immediate from Pontryagin duality.  Let $H$ be the closure of the subgroup of $\widehat{G}$ generated by id.  If $H$ is not all of $\widehat{G}$, then there is a nontrivial character $\widehat{G}\to\mathbb{T}$ that is trivial on $H$.  But every character on $\widehat{G}$ is evaluation at some element of $G$, so this gives a nontrivial element $g\in G$ such that $h(g)=1$ for all $h\in H$.  In particular, taking $h=\mathrm{id}$, this says $g=1$, which is a contradiction.

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $f:G\to T$ is an injective homomorphism of locally compact abelian groups, the dual homomorphism $\widehat{T}\to\widehat{G}$ has dense image.  (In your case $T=\mathbb{T}$ and $f=\mathrm{id}$, and its dual is just the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\widehat{G}$ of the subgroup generated by id.)